# Onclick Javascript - How to include Case Comments in the email body that is invoked through javascript mailto:

Tags: javascript

I have difficulty in getting the case comments to the body of the email when invoked through javascript through a button. I have a custom button called Send Email and when clicked on Send Email, it opens the email client (In my case outlook). The To, CC, Subject are all filled through field reference in the javascript but i am not able to fill the body of the email with the last case comment that is public.
The javascript (Onclick Javascript under custom button) i have is as below

```
javascript:location.href='mailto:{!Contact.Email};{!Case.Additional_To_Emails__c}?CC=support@aryaka.com&SUBJECT=[{!Case.CaseNumber}] [{!Case.Subject}][{!Case.Ref_ID__c}] &BODY={!Case.Last_Case_Comment}';
```

`{!Case.Last_Case_Comment}` is not getting filled in the body of the email. Any suggestions to make it work?

Regards
Deepak

Comment: Can you try hard coding some text without spaces to the body. I think this is because of `Last_Case_Comment` is having spaces in between words

Comment: Are you sure it's {!Case.Last_Case_Comment} and not {!Case.Last_Case_Comment__c}

Comment: {!Case.Last_Case_Comment} is a standard merge field. i dont have control on that and i checked it again. there is no _c at the end. If I give some text in place of {!Case.Last_Case_Comment}, it works. But i want the case's last comment to be added to the email's body

Comment: try assigning `{!Case.Last_Case_Comment}` to a JS variable and put an `alert()` as a first step. If it's giving correct value then replace all the spaces in the `Last_Case_Comment` with `%20` and use that in the `mailto` function

Comment: Thank you all for looking into this. i used JSINHTMLENCODE to wrap it and after this, its working.